# Sent UDP package to NTP server and receive time (lwip, Cortex M3, Stellaris LM3S6965 Evaluation Board)

Tags: c, sockets, udp, cortex-m, lwip

I'm working with Cortex M3, Stellaris® LM3S6965 Evaluation Board. I want to display the time of a NTP server on my oled screen. First I want to get a reply from the NTP server. I searched that the server works with UDP. And It gives me a timestamp. I'm using the LWIP library.

I'm trying to sent the server an UDP packet and I want to display the recieved packet data on the display (the timestamp)..

So I think I have to sent a udp package to the TNP server and recieve the timestamp.

But somehow its not working. I hope you guys can help me find a solution.

EDIT:

I also found some more information about NTP [here](http://www.endruntechnologies.com/pdf/NTP-Intro.pdf)

Updated program:

```
// Function gets called when we recieve data
err_t RecvUTPCallBack(void *arg, struct udp_pcb *upcb, struct pbuf *p, struct ip_addr *addr, u16_t port){
    RIT128x96x4Enable(1000000);
    RIT128x96x4StringDraw("ENTERING CALLBACK", 40, 40, 11);


    volatile int totaal_lengte=0;
    totaal_lengte = p->tot_len;
    volatile int line=40;

    while(1){

        RIT128x96x4Enable(1000000);
        RIT128x96x4StringDraw(p->payload+1, 0, line, 15);
        line+=8;
        if(p->len != p->tot_len){
            p=p->next;
        }
        else break;
    }
    pbuf_free(p);
}

int main(void){
                //UDP
                struct udp_pcb * udp_con_new;
                struct ip_addr ntp_server;
                udp_con_new = udp_new();
                IP4_ADDR(&ntp_server,65,55,21,13); // time.windows.com
                udp_connect(udp_con_new,&ntp_server,123);

                struct pbuf * p;
                p = 0;

                udp_send(udp_con_new, p);

                //udp_recv(upcb,RecvUTPCallBack, recv_arg);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending any data. UDP is connection-less, and [these random docs](http://www.ecoscentric.com/ecospro/doc/html/ref/lwip-api-raw-udp-connect.html) for the `udp_connect()` function (which do seem to match what you're using) say:

> This function does not generate any network traffic, but only sets the remote address of the pcb.

You must construct a valid request packet for NTP, and then send it using `udp_send()`. For details on how to do this, and generally a lot of information on NTP which you seem to need, read the [current IEEE specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905). Enjoy.

Comment: What data do I need to sent to the NTP server then?

Comment: @Sharpless512 See the NTP specification, it tells you the format of the NTP packets.

Comment: there is alot information but not really explained what I need to send.

Comment: I updated my program, I don't completly understand how it knows it need to call the function when data is recieved.